Rendering jupyter notebooks to PDF using LaTex generates unwanted characters?
Cross-posting on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78337970/fix-rendering-issue-when-converting-jupyter-notebooks-to-pdf. I bring this question over TeX sub as it may be also relevant and perhaps there's another way to understand the problem.
So, I'm converting a jupyter notebook to PDF format but have issue with the rendering. A method I use is pdf conversion via LaTex. This method can break long texts to multiple lines. However, the problem is it generates unwanted characters/symbols at the end of each line and the beginning of the new line, as seen below:

Do you know if this problem can be solved? I think I use nbconvert for the conversion if that's relevant.

Having indicators for soft line breaks seems to be a design choice of whoever made nbconvert (or whatever you are using); it's a feature, not a bug. This should be configurable somewhere on the python side. Probably off-topic here...
